# Image does not show up in surfaceview

Tags: java, android

I load a png image about like 5px each side,

```
Image img =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,R.drawable.smt);
```

but it does not show up in surfaceview.

When I use bigger image, there is no problem.

Anybody for help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have given padding in image view control like below ..

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
    android:id="@+id/amIvData"
    android:padding="5px"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/amACt"
    android:src="@drawable/a"
    android:onClick="imgBtn"/>
```

other wise post your code.